# Error 405: Method Not allowed flask, ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, python-2.7, flask

Just trying to submit the form data to the MySQL DB using Ajax & Python- Flask, but the same error "method not allowed" appearing again and again.. kindly look at the codes and help me out...

```
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" Align="center">Create Account</h4>
        </div>
        <form role="form" method="POST">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p id="msg"></p>
          <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" Placeholder="Email"></input><br />
          <input class="form-control" name="firstname" type="text" Placeholder="First Name"></input><br />
          <input class="form-control" name="lastname" type="text" Placeholder="Last Name"></input><br />
          <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" Placeholder="Password"></input><br />
          <input class="form-control" type="password" Placeholder="Confirm Password"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="btncheck" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" >Signup</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>    

$(function(){

  $("#btncheck").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: '/signup',
    type: 'POST'
    success: function(res){
          console.log(res);

        }

  });
  });
```

Python Code

```
@app.route("/signup", methods=['POST','GET'])
def signup():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            _email =request.form["email"]
            _firstname = request.form["firstname"]
            _lastname = request.form["lastname"]
            _password = request.form["password"]
            con = mysql.connect()
            cursor = con.cursor()
            if _email and _firstname and _password:
                cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO signpp (
                                            user_email,
                                            user_fname,
                                            user_lname,
                                            user_password)
                                    VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(_email,_firstname,_lastname,_password))

                data = cursor.fetchall()
                if len(data) is 0:
                    con.commit()
                    return jsonify(data = "User created successfully !")
                else:
                    return jsonify(str(data[0]))


    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('error.html', error = str(e))        

    cursor.close()
    con.close()
```

Error : Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Comment: If my answer helped, please consider an up vote or marking my answer as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does your web service responding to your ajax call expect any data, I assume so since your doing a POST?  If so I don't see where your passing that in, and could throw this error ( non matching signature ).  data:  yourDataHere

As an example:

```
var params = { StateId: stateid };

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    url: 'YOURURLHERE',
    data: params,
    error: function (request, status, error) { 
         alert('Error: ' + error); 
    },
    success: function (result) {
        $('#body').html(result);

                        }
});
```

Comment: Do you have the error sectioned defined in your ajax call?  When you debug do you hit the success section?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED) Error in the console...

Answer (score 0):

I am sure if it is a typo or not but you forgot a comma after `type: 'POST'`.

On a side note you are sending sensitive data such as a user password in plaintext. I would suggest encrypting it first. One of the most common techniques is [bcrypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/2.0.0)

Comment: Where are is your variable storing the data your trying to post?  I do not see that in your code in the ajax call @LokeshTiwari

Comment: @MisterPositive after updating the data variable its working well, thanx a lot

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. If you would could you upload my answer or mark it as the answer? @LokeshTiwari